# Why Next JS(13.4.6 with app directory) build is failing after integrating storybook (7.1.1)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, storybook

Storybook: **7.1.1**
Next JS: **13.4.6** with app directory, typescript & tailwind css

This folder structure got created after storybook integration. Storybook is working fine.

[image]

Got the following error on running `yarn build`

[image]

Can somebody please help me to resolve this error?
Thanks in advance.

I have tried `yarn build` and it should successfully build the Next project.

Comment: There is something wrong with linting `src/stories/Page.tsx`. Please share at least your IDE screenshot